# Is this a proper Bluebook citation for a Court of Federal Claims case?

Tags: legal-research, federal-courts, legal-citation

I am a forensic psychologist who happens to prefer Bluebook citation style over APA style. I mention this fact because while I have some experience using Bluebook citation style, it pales in comparison to the experience and knowledge of most of you.

I use the online [Bluebook (20th ed.)](https://www.legalbluebook.com/Public/TwentiethEdition.aspx). I have read Rule 10 - Cases (p. 94 in the print version) several times. But I am not sure how to cite a published decision from the Court of Federal Claims. Here is my best guess, which I assume contains errors:

> *See:* *QTC Medical Services, Inc. v. United States*, Fed. Cl., No. 17-80C, Memorandum Opinion and Order, filed under seal 23 June 2017;
>   reissued for publication 12 July 2017.

The court decision is at https://ecf.cofc.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/show_public_doc?2017cv0080-69-0 (PDF)

Please let me know what I need to change to make this citation correct.

Comment: If one of you would create a tag for _bluebook_ and maybe one for _cite_ or _citation_, that would probably be helpful for searching and such.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive!

Comment: Services should be Servs. I do not know that you need both dates, especially because there was no material change (or in this case, redaction) made between each. Because it would probably get listed in a reporter on the date of "reissued for publication," I *think* you would just go with that date. Also, are you citing a specific quote or info from a specific part of the decision? If so, you would need a pincite to that page #. This is probably too recent to be in a reporter, so you'd also need the website at the end, I believe.

Comment: @A.fm. - Thank you very much. Makes good sense to me! :0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reissued for publication doesn't come up very often and I don't believe that there is a specific rule for it, so there is a certain amount of discretion in how that is stated. I would cite it as follows:

*QTC Medical Servs., Inc. v. United States*, No. 17-80C, 17-83C (Ct. Cl. June 23, 2017) *reissued for publication* (July 12, 2017).

The date of a case is ordinarily the date that it is decided.

If you were making a pin point cite to the seventh page of the case, you would add:

*QTC Medical Servs., Inc. v. United States*, No. 17-80C, 17-83C, slip op. at 7 (Ct. Cl. June 23, 2017) *reissued for publication* (July 12, 2017).

Either way, the citation would have to be updated when it was reported in an official reporter or on Westlaw or Lexis if you had access to those sources.

As of July 31, I was not able to locate a citation to this particular case in an official reporter, which usually lags a few months.

I don't have access to Lexis and I'm not sure that this search would be within my plan on Westlaw, so I haven't confirmed either of those (I usually use a "budget" legal research system called "Casemaker").

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "Ct. Cl." refers to _Court of Claims Reports_, published 1863–1982. I used "Fed. Cl." per Bluebook table _T1.1 - Federal Judicial and Legislative Materials_ (p. 233). However, that abbreviation refers to the _Federal Claims Reporter_, published by Thomson Reuters. The [Wikipedia article on the court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Court_of_Federal_Claims) states "(in case citations, Fed. Cl. or C.F.C.)." On the other hand, Bluebook table _T7 - Court Names_ lists "Fed. Cl." for the court. {continued...}

Comment: I looked up a recent Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit case to see how they were doing it. In a recent case, [MENDEZ v. US](http://www.cafc.uscourts.gov/sites/default/files/opinions-orders/17-1236.Opinion.5-4-2017.1.PDF), I noticed three things: _i_) In the text, they abbreviated Court of Federal Claims as "CFC"; _ii_) If a CFC decision has been published in the _Federal Claims Reporter_, they cite as follows (example): "Mendez v. United States (Mendez I), 103 Fed. Cl. 370,
374 (2012)". _iii_) If a CFC decision has _not_ been published in the _Federal Claims Reporter_ {continued...}

Comment: {continued from above comment...} they cite to Westlaw (example): "Mendez v. United States (Mendez IV), No. 11-160C, 2014 WL 2772590, at *1 (Fed. Cl. June 18, 2014)." Note in that example that the parenthetical abbreviation for the court is "Fed. Cl.", which is consistent with Bluebook's instructions (although Bluebook could explain it with greater clarity and precision).

Comment: So, I'm thinking this might be correct:  _QTC Medical Servs., Inc. v. United States_, No. 17-80C (Fed. Cl. June 23, 2017), _published July 12, 2017_, https://ecf.cofc.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/show_public_doc?2017cv0080-69-0 . What do you all think?

Comment: Back in the 15th edition when I learned my blue booking, the abbreviation for the federal court of claims (and not just the reporter) was Ct. Cl., but perhaps it has changed in the later editions. You absolutely need both docket numbers in the consolidated case No. 17-80C, 17-83C. You ordinarily wouldn't include a URL in a case citation although you might embed a link in the case name in an electronic version. Dates of opinions go in parenthesis.

Comment: <You absolutely need both docket numbers in the consolidated case No. 17-80C, 17-83C.> - Thank you - much appreciated!

Comment: <You ordinarily wouldn't include a URL in a case citation although you might embed a link in the case name in an electronic version.> - Excellent idea! I did just that.  <Dates of opinions go in parenthesis.> - Good catch! I totally missed that. Thanks again for all your help. :O)

Comment: Here's my final version:  _See: QTC Medical Servs., Inc. v. United States_, & _Veterans Evaluation Servs., Inc. v. United States_, [No. 17-80C, No. 17-83C](https://ecf.cofc.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/show_public_doc?2017cv0083-81-0) (Fed. Cl. July 12, 2017).

Comment: Bravo, @ohwilleke! I'm ashamed to say I found myself rather excited to come back to this post and read about Bluebooking. I found one more revision to note, Mr. Worthen: *Medical* should be *Med.*

Comment: @A.fm. As of the 15th edition, "Med." was not in the list of approved Bluebook abbreviations for case names. Maybe it has changed since then.

Comment: If you submit an article to a law review journal, is it acceptable to use the bluebook 15th edition, or should you use the newest blue book, which is the 20th edition?

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at the 19th edition, don't have the 20th. Go with what the 20th, or the most recent at any time you are writing, says. Not that the Bluebook system is anything but arbitrary decisions made by law students, but I suppose your goal is to get your article published not stick it to the system ;)

Comment: If you citations were perfect and accurate when you submitted your article what would all the hapless 1L citation checkers do?

Comment: LMAO! ... And I'm writing a white paper for a federal advisory committee, only some of whom are attorneys, so I'll tell my perfectionistic self to chill.